# How to register JdbcToXXXConverter in Calcite?

Tags: rules, conventions, apache-calcite

I have a Calcite convention, named: XxxConvention,
and a ConverterRule named: JdbcToXxxConverterRule, which needs a JdbcConventio as parameter.(there are multi JdbcSchema, thus multi JdbcConvention in application context )

i was thinking to register JdbcToXxxConverterRule in JdbcConvention, but found out it's hard to achieve that.

in JdbcConvention

```
 @Override public void register(RelOptPlanner planner) {
    for (RelOptRule rule : JdbcRules.rules(this)) {
      planner.addRule(rule);
    }
    planner.addRule(CoreRules.FILTER_SET_OP_TRANSPOSE);
    planner.addRule(CoreRules.PROJECT_REMOVE);
  }
```

JdbcConvention retrive rules using `JdbcRules.rules(this)`,  `JdbcRules.rules(this)`'s result is unchangeable:

```
  public static List<RelOptRule> rules(JdbcConvention out) {
    final ImmutableList.Builder<RelOptRule> b = ImmutableList.builder();
    foreachRule(out, b::add);
    return b.build();
  }

 private static void foreachRule(JdbcConvention out,
      Consumer<RelRule<?>> consumer) {
    consumer.accept(JdbcToEnumerableConverterRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcJoinRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcCalcRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcProjectRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcFilterRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcAggregateRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcSortRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcUnionRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcIntersectRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcMinusRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcTableModificationRule.create(out));
    consumer.accept(JdbcValuesRule.create(out));
  }
```

so how can i rigister my JdbcToXxxConvention in Calcite? Look forward to hearing your thoughts.